# Plotting Lat Lon Subset of Xarray Global Data

Tags: python, plot, subset, coordinates, python-xarray

I am very stuck here on trying to plot a subset of lat, long data from an array in python. I have an xarray of dimension we can call "global_data" of (73, 144) with data arranged by lat (73) and long (144) that plots a nice plot with my code for the entire globe. However, I need to select a subset of this lat, lon data so that it plots given the range I give it (for the USA only).
The "global_data" looks like this:

```
<xarray.DataArray (lat: 73, lon: 144)>
array([[ 1.1423118 ,  1.1418152 ,  1.1437986 , ...,  1.1403227 ,
         1.1362497 ,  1.1439507 ],
       [ 0.49379024,  0.42622158,  0.3565474 , ...,  0.70473236,
         0.63061965,  0.5644286 ],
       [ 0.1380711 ,  0.19678137,  0.2836361 , ...,  0.24298143,
         0.16488086,  0.12564908],
       ...,
       [ 0.18887411,  0.25456694,  0.30384657, ..., -0.08306076,
         0.01299069,  0.10468105],
       [ 0.37176454,  0.4389612 ,  0.50888765, ...,  0.16366327,
         0.23381352,  0.30179456],
       [ 0.6100794 ,  0.61286193,  0.6167843 , ...,  0.6154521 ,
         0.6117071 ,  0.610261  ]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float32 90.0 87.5 85.0 82.5 80.0 ... -82.5 -85.0 -87.5 -90.0
  * lon      (lon) float32 0.0 2.5 5.0 7.5 10.0 ... 350.0 352.5 355.0 357.5
```

I need a new xarray "usa_data" that is bounded by lat_range = 25, 50 and lon_range = -125, -66. I have tried using .sel, .isel and slice with this data above and I get either no data to plot or a plot of the data in a completely surprising place like "Africa' given what I think are USA coordinates. Thank you for your help!!

I have included here my first plot of the global data:

[image]

Here is an attempt that plots a subset using 'isel' but a final USA map was obtained by trial and error and I'm not sure it's correct or why the coordinates below "work" for the USA map. Any ideas?

```
usa_data = global_data.isel(lon=slice(-55,-23),lat=slice(13,29))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
contourf = anomspeed_us.plot.contourf(
    ax=ax, levels=np.arange(-5,5.1,0.5),extend=
    'both',cmap='RdBu_r',
    add_colorbar=True,
    cbar_kwargs={'label': 'Anomalous Wind Speed'})
ax.coastlines()
states = cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature(category='cultural', 
                                      name='admin_1_states_provinces_lines',
                                      scale='50m', facecolor='none')
ax.add_feature(states, linewidth=0.5, edgecolor='black')
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linestyle='-')
ax.gridlines()
plt.title('Anomalous Wind Speed for Week')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Your longitude data goes 0 to 360.  Where is the prime meridian?  Is it 0 or 180?

Comment: Can you how you tried to use `sel()`? In general, the more you can do to show what you've tried and what isn't working, the more folks will be able to help you here.

Comment: Can't you just do `data[16:27,170:194]`?  (First coordinate is `36 - lat x 2/5`, second is `144 - lon x 2/5`).

Comment: Tim - i assume prime meridian is 180. I'm not following your second reply above. thanks,

Comment: i have added my most successful attempt. thank you,

Comment: `usa_data = global_data.sel(lat=(global_data.lat >= 25) & (global_data.lat <= 50), lon=(global_data.lon >= -125%360) & (global_data.lon <= -66%360))`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Xarray's `.sel()` method which is meant for coordinate based selection.

```py
# lat_range = 25, 50 and lon_range = -125, -66 (or 235, 294)
regional_data = global_data.isel(
    lon=slice(360-125, 360-23), lat=slice(25, 50)
)

regional_data.plot.contourf(...)
```